# fullPage js scrolls wrong height in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I am developing a website with fullPage js to create a scrolling site.

The scrolling works fine in Chrome and Firefox but in Internet Explorer it is completely off.

The scroll goes in between pages and to the wrong pages and you can't use the site much at all. I don't know why this is happening.

[www.mpaccione.com/correlation-one/index.html](http://www.mpaccione.com/correlation-one/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) you can read the following:

> **Be careful!** data-anchor tags can not have the same value as any ID element on the site (or NAME element for IE).

Looking your resulting HTML code I can see how you use the anchor `Employers` and the id `employers`:

```
<div id='employers' class='howWorks grayBg'></div>
```

IE might not be case sensitive.

Comment: I was not expecting the great fullpage master himself.

You have completely solved my problem.

IE IS NOT CASE SENSITIVE!